# How to get a anchor link text inside a javascript and calling with arguments

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a function like to get a user from server and i got it . Now i create a links for each users using `a href` inside `java script` . This is working fine . Now i want to execute a function when i user click the link (with the corresponding user name)

```
var User_id = document.querySelector(".sidebar-name");

//getting array of user

function list(user){

   User_id.innerHTML = "";

   for( i = 0; i < user.length; i++ ){

      User_id.innerHTML+= "<a href='#' onclick = 'javascript:calluser(this);' style='text-decoration:none'>" + user[i] + "</a>" + "<br />"; 

    }
}



function calluser(this){

  alert(user);
 // i need to print the corresponding username or anchor text .
// how can i solve this ? 

}
```

I tried with `id` inside `a href` . But this is not unique so it won't work . How can i solve this ?

Comment: Does `alert(this.innerHTML)` work?

Comment: `href="#"` is a link to the top of the page. Don't use a link when you want a button. Use a button. `innerHTML` is nightmare. Use DOM instead. `createElement`, `appendChild`, `addEventListener`, etc.

Comment: Also, make the id in the for loop unique by using the variable i appended to your id. Eg. ...id='myid" + i + "'...

Comment: I'm not shure you need 'javascript:', just onclick='calluser(this)' should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"function calluser(this) "* Is a Syntax error.

Rename *"this"* with something else like *"a"*:

```
var User_id = document.querySelector(".sidebar-name");

function list(user){
    User_id.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i=0; i<user.length; i++){
        User_id.innerHTML+= "<a href='jacascript:void();' onclick='javascript:calluser(this);' style='text-decoration:none'>" + user[i] + "</a>" + "<br />";
    }
}

function calluser(a){
    alert(a.text);
}
```

Comment: thanks .. working fine  .. But what happen when i use  ` onclick='calluser("+username[i]+") ` ?

Comment: I need more info what's in the "username" variable ? if you use "this" ("calluser(this)"),  you are passing an OBJECT (the anchor) to the function "calluser". Therefore you will use the sintax "alert(a.text)"; if you wont to pass the text directly: "calluser(user[i])", you are passing a STRING to the function; therefore you should use "alert(a)"